# SPRING/THYMELEAF: How to fill a list in form and append another line to the form?

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an object:

```
InvoiceData
    String name
    Date date
    List<InvoiceTask>
```

The InvoiceTask has 3 fields:

```
InvoiceTask
    String name
    String project
    BigDecimal hours
```

I have created a thymeleaf formular that is creating an InvoiceData object and persisting it into my MongoDB instance, but it contains only `Name` and `Date`. I have no Idea how to modify this form to add not only a task, but multiple tasks (probably with a button "Add task" inside the form).

The controller that is redirecting to `add.html` looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}")
public String addPage(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
    InvoiceData invoiceData = new InvoiceData();
    model.addAttribute("contractorid", id);
    model.addAttribute("invoicedata", invoiceData);
    return "add";
}
```

The controller that is persising the InvoiceData looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addinvoice/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String addInvoice(@PathVariable("id") String id, InvoiceData data, Model model) {
    Contractor contractor = contractorRepository.findById(id).get();
    data.setData(contractor.getContractorData());
    if (contractor.getInvoices() == null) {
        contractor.setInvoices(new ArrayList<InvoiceData>());
    }
    contractor.getInvoices().add(data);
    invoiceDataRepository.save(data);
    contractorRepository.save(contractor);
    model.addAttribute("contractor", contractor);
    return "index";
```

and the Thymeleaf template for the InvoiceData looks like this (**it doesnt have the InvoiceTask list yet!**):

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{addinvoice/{id}(id=${contractorid})}" th:object="${invoicedata}" method="post">
            <ul class="form-style-1">
                <li>
                    <label>Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="receptionDate">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Date<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="date" th:field="*{orderDate}" id="orderDate">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

I'll be honest, I don't know where to start here...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a wrapper class (a DTO?)to pass the invoices to create with the their respectives tasks. For

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}")
public String addPage(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
    InvoiceDataDTO invoiceData = new InvoiceDataDTO();

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
          invoiceData.addTask(new invoiceTask()) 
    }

    model.addAttribute("invoiceData", invoiceData);
    return "add";
}
```

In your thymleaf form you have to display the constructed DTO, as following :

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/invoices/save}" th:object="${invoicesData}"
  method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" th:value="Save">
        <input type="reset" id="resetButton" name="reset" th:value="Reset"/>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Name</th>
                    <th> Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="invoiceTask, itemStat : *{invoicesTaks}">
                    <td><input th:field="*{invoicesTasks[__${itemStat.index}__].name}" /></td>
                    <td><input th:field="*{invoicesTasks[__${itemStat.index}__].project}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

As you see you get the model attribute of the invoiceDataDTO with already added empty tasks.

After the object fill you only have to save.